# the two angles a and b both have the terminal side in the 2nd quadrant and cosa= -1/8 and sinb = 3/4. find the exact value of sin(a-b)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The two angles a and b both have the terminal side in the 2nd quadrant and cosa=-1/8 and sinb=3/4. find the exact value of sin(a-b).

Comment: well so far i honestly do not know where to start so i have nothing yet

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-cos A \sin B$$

$\sin A= \sqrt{1-\cos^2 A}$
$\cos B= -\sqrt{1-\sin^2 B}$

Comment: so to find sina i can use cosa using that first formula?

Comment: @WolfieG Yes, you can