# Suppose that $\cos a=-\frac{8}{17}$ for $\pi < a < 3\pi/2$ find $\sin 2a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $\cos A= -\frac{8}{17}$ for $\pi < A < 3\pi/2$ find $\sin 2A$. how is this question solved and in what steps ?

Comment: `how is this question solved` In a very similar way to the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272274/the-two-angles-a-and-b-both-have-the-terminal-side-in-the-2nd-quadrant-and-cosa) you just asked a couple of hours ago. Here you have $\sin(2A)=\sin(A+A)=\sin(A)\cos(A)+\cos(A)\sin(A)\,$. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @dxiv I just don't know where to start , I've done problems with the stuff that has to do with sin,cos and tan but have never came across the questions like the ones I posted so I just don't know how to start

Comment: Use $\,\sin(2A) = 2 \sin(A) \cos(A)\,$ from my previous comment as a starting point. You know $\,\cos(A)\,$, then calculate $\,\sin(A)\,$ just like was pointed out in the answer to the other question. Choose the right sign for $\,\sin(A)\,$ knowing that $\,A \in \left(\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\,$, then substitute in the formula and calculate $\,\sin(2A)\,$. If you get stuck along the way, edit your question and post the progress, but please *try* something first.

Comment: @dxiv to find sina would it be radical( 1-(-8/7)^2 ?

Comment: Yes, but replace $-8/7$ with whatever the value of $\cos A$ actually is. Note that $\,-8/7 \lt -1\,$, which is outside the range of $\cos\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I'm lost a bit , so cosA is actually another value other then what's given but a value in between pi and 3pi/2 ? How would I find that ?

Comment: $\cos(A)$ is $-8/\color{red}{1}7$ but you had that mistyped as $-8/7$ in the last commment, and in the title of the question before the latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tools**

$$ 
\sin 2\theta = 2\cos\theta \sin \theta
\tag{1}
$$

$$
 \sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{ 1 - \cos^{2} \theta }
$$

---

**Data**

Let the angle
$$
 \theta = \arccos \left( -\frac{8}{17} \right)
$$
then the sine is
$$
\sin \theta = -\frac{15}{17}
$$
**Solution**
$$
 \sin 2\theta = 2 \cos\theta \sin \theta = 
2 
\left( -\frac{8}{17}\right)
\left( -\frac{15}{17}\right)
=
\frac{240}{289}
$$

[image: angle]

Comment: Except for your slip in the sign of the sine in the third quadrant, this is perfect. +1

Comment: @dxiv, @ Lubin: Thanks for the careful reading and comments. (Can't notify 2 users in one comment it seems.)